# Function creation - "Undefined name" - Python

Tags: python, string, function, python-2.7, undefined

I'm writing some code that reads words from a text file and sorts them into a dictionary. It actually all runs fine, but for reference here it is:

```
def find_words(file_name, delimiter = " "):
"""
A function for finding the number of individual words, and the most popular words, in a given file.
The process will stop at any line in the file that starts with the word 'finish'.
If there is no finish point, the process will go to the end of the file.


Inputs:  file_name: Name of file you want to read from, e.g. "mywords.txt"
         delimiter: The way the words in the file are separated e.g. " " or ", "
                  : Delimiter will default to " " if left blank.

Output: Dictionary with all the words contained in the given file, and how many times each word appears.

"""

words = []
dictt = {}
with open(file_name, 'r') as wordfile:
    for line in wordfile:
        words = line.split(delimiter)
        if words[0]=="finish": 
            break             

        # This next part is for filling the dictionary 
        # and correctly counting the amount of times each word appears.

        for i in range(len(words)):
            a = words[i]
            if a=="\n" or a=="":   
                continue
            elif dictt.has_key(a)==False: 
                dictt[words[i]] = 1  
            else:
                dictt[words[i]] = int(dictt.get(a)) + 1 
return dictt
```

The problem is that it only works if the arguments are given as string literals, e.g, this works:

```
test = find_words("hello.txt", " " )
```

But this doesn't:

```
test = find_words(hello.txt, )
```

The error message is *undefined name 'hello'*

I don't know how to alter the function arguments such that I can enter them without speech marks.

Thanks!

Comment: These "speech marks" are called quotes, and are the only way the interpreter has to differentiate strings from identifiers. Yes, machines are dumb, and interpreters are too, that's life.

Comment: Why do you want to enter the arguments without quotes?

Comment: If this error message, or its cause, genuinely confuses you, then I am skeptical that you actually wrote this code, or understand it. Hint: on the line that reads `if words[0]=="finish":`, for example, did it occur to you to try `if words[0]==finish:` instead? Can you see why that would not work? On the flip side of that equation, can you see why `words[0]` does not always evaluate to `"w"`?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, obviously he did not write the code.

Comment: @bgusach Very late reply but I'd just like to tell you that I did write that code. At the time I was very new to programming, and was completely ignorant of the fact that there's a difference between words written in quotation marks and words written plainly. A fantastically rookie error, in hindsight, but that shouldn't detract from my wider ability to write programming logic. I got an A* for that project in the end, so I guess I was mostly doing things right..

Comment: Stuart, to be honest I don't know why I wrote that back then. It sounds quite arrogant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out I just misunderstood what was being asked. I've had it clarified by the course leader now.

As I am now fully aware, a function definition needs to be told when a string is being entered, hence the quote marks being required.

I admit full ignorance over my depth of understanding of how it all works - I thought you could pretty much put any assortment of letters and/or numbers in as an argument and then you can manipulate them *within* the function definition.

My ignorance may stem from the fact that I'm quite new to Python, having learned my coding basics on C++ where, if I remember correctly (it was well over a year ago), functions are defined with each argument being specifically set up as their type, e.g.

```
int max(int num1, int num2)
```

Whereas in Python you don't quite do it like that.

Thanks for the attempts at help (and ridicule!)

Problem is sorted now.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, you define that name:

```
class hello:
  txt = "hello.txt"
```

But joking aside, all the argument values in a function call are expressions. If you want to pass a string literally you'll have to make a string literal, using the quotes. Python is not a text preprocessor like m4 or cpp, and expects the entire program text to follow its syntax.